Terrraform: Ignore specific value when using aws_org_org data call
I am new to terraform and need to exclude a specific value from the each.value in target_id from the below:
The below data source is used to list all accounts in the org
# List all account IDs in the organization
data "aws_organizations_organization" "example" {}


resource "aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment" "example" {
  instance_arn       = tolist(data.aws_ssoadmin_instances.sso_instance.arns)[0]
  permission_set_arn = "permission_set_arn"  
  principal_id       = "groupid"
  principal_type     = "GROUP"
  for_each           = tolist(data.aws_organizations_organization.example)
  target_id          = each.value
  target_type        = "AWS_ACCOUNT"
}

Above resource fails due to my newness to terraform. I'd like to list all the account IDs from the data.aws_organizations_organization.example block but exclude specific account, any help is appreciated!
I have tried several different ways, using tolist and toset without success.
I need a filter to exclude one value from the data call list.

Below is a sample using an intermediary variable (locals) with a for loop and an if statement to filter the data, I'm not sure what to filter on so this is just an example...
data "aws_organizations_organization" "example" {}

locals {
  organizations = {
    for x in data.aws_organizations_organization.example : x.arn => x.id
    if x.id != "123"
  }
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment" "example" {
  for_each     = local.organizations
  target_id    = each.value
  target_type  = "AWS_ACCOUNT"
  ...
}

Here is a link to the official documentation:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#filtering-elements
